# Knowing the internal IP of an http request coming through NAT on a machine with multiple NICs?

Tags: windows, wcf, network-programming

Imagine a Windows box, which:

- hosts a WCF service
- has multiple NICs
- sits behind NAT

When a user issues a request to the service (on top of the WCF infrastructure), he uses the external address assigned to the target machine by the NAT.

I have to write some piece of code inside the WCF service, which must know which of the several NICs that the machine has was used to actually handle the network traffic. How does this code identify the NIC is less important - it could be its MAC address (the best) or it could be the (internal) IP address of the NIC.

How can I do it?

**EDIT1**

I will try to supply the question context. There are two agents. Both expose the same WCF service. In addition, one of the agents can be instructed to start probing the network towards the second agent in the following fashion:

1. Agent A is asked to probe the network to agent B
2. Agent A negotiates with agent B the UDP port to utilize for the sake of probing using the WCF service exposed by the agent B.
3. Once negotiation is over, the agent A starts some custom protocol over UDP, where the agent B acts as the server - i.e. it binds to the UDP port negotiated in the previous item.

Binding to a UDP port requires two pieces - the IP address and UDP port, where the IP address can either be a specific IP address or * (to bind to all the IP addresses associated with the machine). The latter option is not good for us - I will omit the reasons. This leaves us the former option - binding to the specific IP address. However, when the agent B is behind NAT, the IP address used to talk to the WCF service is the external IP address assigned to the agent by the NAT. Binding, on the other hand, requires the respective internal IP address - how to get it?

Comment: Can you share what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have added the question context.

Comment: So i am just trying to understand. Does Agent A and Agent B provide the same web service but with different protocols? Can you utilize different URIs? such as myserver:8080/AgentA and myserver:8080/AgentB?

Comment: The web service is only there to negotiate the port for some low level protocol over UDP to be run between the agents. In your example, myserver:8080/AgentA and myserver:8080/AgentB refer the same machine - myserver. This is not the case. Agent A is on machine alice and agent B is on machine bob. Possible urls are http://alice/Agent and http://bob/Agent. However, if bob has multiple NICs, then referring http://bob/Agent from different networks may utilize different NICs of bob (each having a different IP address)

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly you want to communicate to a WCF service via a specific port that sits behind a router running a dhcp server?  If so can you just use port forwarding on your router to route all traffic on a specific port to a specific internal ip address?  Assuming you have the router assigning static ips to certain MAC addresses.  Also assuming I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: So, let me see if I understand – you are suggesting to configure the router with a static ip and port, and make the agent listen to that specific ip/port pair? That’s exactly what I want to do, but instead of hard coding the internal address of the agent, I want it to discover it on its own. (Just to make sure - the machine has multiple NICs and I need to know the one used in the particular WCF communication session)

Comment: I am struggling to understand the main problem. Why do web services need to know which NIC the request came from?

Comment: The web service is needed to prepare the stage for the "real" thing - some custom UDP based protocol. The server side of this custom UDP protocol cannot (must not) bind to *. Instead, it must bind to the specific NIC, which would be used for the communication. Which NIC? The same NIC used to handle the web service traffic. One of the tasks of the web service is therefore to deduce the NIC used to communicate with it and start the custom UDP protocol server, instructing it to bind to that NIC.

Answer (score 3):

Can you check the OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress (it's an EndpointAddress) inside a WCF operation?

As a side note, getting the remote address can be done with:

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint =
    prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string ip = endpoint.Address;
```

--larsw

Comment: This makes sense, and then you create UDP binding in the code using this address which is specific to the NIC.

Comment: I am trying to validate your answer, but this is not so easy, since I do not have the right environment at home. But I give +1 nonetheless and if no one provides a better answer  - you are the man.

Answer (score -1):

To get the MAC use
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetPhysicalAddress();

All Nics:
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

to find out what is the real listening ip address you can write a code that listen to your port on each address and ping it from an agent emulator to see that the address is valid.

Cheers,

Gilad

Comment: This is not really the answer, is it? Because what is the point of listening on each address, if I want to avoid it in the first place? If I could listen on each address, I would have bound to * and closed the issue. The essence of the question is that I do not want to listen on all the addresses. I want to deduce the NIC used to handle the current WCF request.